# Getting the list of include paths WITH libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I've been facing an issue with CMake and on how to get the path to the included libraries that I use in my C++ project.

The libraries are added such as:

```
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(glm CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

and I've tried to query the following but without success

```
get_property(dirlist DIRECTORY PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(test projname INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

as it only returns what I have added with include_directories() and not the libraries themselves.

Is there any workaround around this?

Answer (score 1):

If the CMake finds the packages, `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `GLM_INCLUDE_DIR` contains path to include files.

```
message("SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
message("GLM_INCLUDE_DIR  : " ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: CMake finds the packages but SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR/SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS are empty. The only thing I can get is SDL2_DIR but it is incorrect too. Same for GLM.
It would also be better to have a solution that would list me the include flags used when building/that are left in compile_commands.json when exported.

Comment: you can check paths with ccmake .. after doing cmake ..

Comment: the goal is to have it automated in the CMake file to export it to a file

Comment: I mean you can see what variables are set for sdl2, glm libs

Comment: SDL2_CONFIG, SDL2_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS, SDL2_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS, SDL2_DIR, SDL2_FOUND, SDL2_VERSION, SDL2_VERSION_COUNT, SDL2_VERSION_MAJOR, SDL2_VERSION_MINOR, SDL2_VERSION_PATCH, SDL2_VERSION_TWEAK and none of them are correct, including SDL2_DIR sadly, and same for glm

Comment: Looks like you have multiple version of SDL2 installed. Are you using linux or windows?